# External request to Wordpress WP-API - Basic Authentication

Tags: wordpress, basic-authentication, guzzle, nonce, wp-api

I'm trying to hit my Wordpress API using Basic Auth with Guzzle (http tool) from my middleware (Laravel).

```
$username = 'myAdminUserName';
$password = 'myAdminPassword';
$uri = 'https://example.com/wp-json/mysite-api/cleared-action';
$response = $this->guzzle->put(
    $uri,
    [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( $username . ':' . $password )
        ],
        'body' => [
            'user_id' => $wordpressId  //passed into this function
        ]
    ]
);
```

It then hits the route set up in my Wordpress API

```
$routes['/mysite-api/cleared-action'] = array(
        array(array($this, 'automatedClearing'), WP_JSON_Server::ACCEPT_JSON 
                                               | WP_JSON_Server::CREATABLE 
                                               | WP_JSON_Server::EDITABLE)
    );
```

However that is as far as it gets.  It does not hit my `automatedClearing` endpoint which looks like this

```
public function automatedClearing() {
    global $container;

    \Groups_User_Group::create( array('user_id' => 2903, 'group_id' => 13));

    $mySiteServices = $container['services'];

    $this->$mySiteServices->sendClearedEmail(2903);  //2903 = user_id
}
```

I've used hardcoded values for the users ID.

I keep getting a 200 response from my call, so it definitely hits the route, but does not execute the endpoint.  The response is basically just an empty one.

My Wordpress access.log shows the route being hit, but my error.log doesn't show anything.  By the way, this is a laravel Homestead (vagrant) box hitting a Wordpress vagrant box.

I'm wondering if this is because the WP-API requires a nonce?  But I thought nonce was only needed within Wordpress, whereas this is an external app hitting Wordpress.

I'm pretty stuck on this.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you try to access your WP endpoint with GET instead of POST?

Comment: @gandra404 I'm using PUT because I'm sending data with which to use in WP

Comment: Ok, but I would like to know if endpoint is reached via GET. This info should help to localize problem.

Comment: @gandra404 GET only works if i add `WP_JSON_Server::READABLE` to the route, otherwise I get a 404 response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to test it using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) ... if this works via postman then you have the problem with laravel or guzzle

Comment: Yup, there is nothing wrong with my `myplugin_api_init`.  I use this plugin for Ajax requests from within my Wordpress plugins, so I know it works.  Technically I don't need `EDITABLE` since I'm 'creating' a user => group relationship.  So I really just need `CREATABLE`. I've changed my verb to POST but still no luck.  It's not even reaching the first line of the endpoint though, which is to add that user to a group.

Comment: Try to test it using postman(https://www.getpostman.com) ... if this works via postman then you hav problem with laravel or guzzle

Comment: There was an error with my endpoint actually...I didn't realize postman worked locally.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You are welcome.
If that helped can you accept my answer?

Comment: Edit your answer to just include the postman info and I will accept